# How to redirect an old domain to a new one - While not having any server for the old domain anymore (so I cant redirect it using .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I had this website: www.example.pro

and now I created a new website using Amazon AWS, and bought a new domain: www.example.com. I defined everything on Route 53 on Amazon. Everything works perfect with the ".com" domain.

Now I have to redirect users who still use the ".pro" to the ".com".

a few months ago I still had a server connected to the .pro domain and had an .htaccess file sending users to the .com website.

Now the old server is terminated, and I'm not sure how to redirect users from .pro to .com

I tried this: (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.pro [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.pro [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

without any success.

Comment: Where is `.pro` domain pointed to?

Comment: Currently it's pointing to nothing. I have it on AWS with an MX record set for the emails. 
I tried using an A record set and sending it to the IP of the website - but I get a strange website with strange fonts.

Comment: Should I open an A record set and point to the "Name Servers" of the .com ?

Comment: I get an error `The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.`

Comment: Sorry I am not a system admin so can't help in that but once you have A record setup above redirect should work fine.

Comment: When the A record points to your new server, you can add a `ServerAlias example.pro www.example.pro` to your main server/virtual host config.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this should work, but I got the `500 error`. @OlafDietsche

Comment: I don't understand why you get a 500 error. What does the error.log say? Do you have a `ServerName` in your main/virtual host configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an A record won't cause a redirect.  For that, you *need* a web server in the mix.  AWS has a service that can do this for you without having to maintain and pay for such a server.

Create an empty bucket in Amazon S3, named www.example.pro and another named example.pro. The bucket names must exactly match the domain, with and without www.

In each bucket, under static website hosting (in bucket properties), and choose "redirect all requests to another domain."

In the "redirect all requests to" box, put `example.com`. (Or www.example.com, the same name in both, wherever you want the users to be redirected to.

Create a hosted zone in Route 53 for example.pro.

Create two A records, one with the hostname empty, select "Yes" for "Alias" then choose the S3 endpoint from the selection box below.

Switch your DNS nameservers with the registrar for the .pro domain to the 4 nameservers that Route 53 assigned to the new hosted zone.

You're done.

S3 is, of course, primarily for storage... but this web site redirection capability is a secondary feature designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: and it's considered as a pure-clean 301 redirect? :)

Comment: It returns a proper, standard HTTP `301` redirect to the same path at the target domain, so it's SEO-friendly and will not drink all your beer.

Comment: I guess, this is the relevant documentation? [Configure a Bucket for Website Hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html)

Comment: I started following what you wrote, I cant enable a website hosting and in the same time use the 'Redirect all requests to another host name' option :S

Comment: oh. sorry, it just took time for the S3 to get it self ready :P 
Still working on it..

Comment: I get my website loading 
and in the end this error: 

This webpage is not available

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Google Chrome could not load the webpage because www.example.com took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it has been 100% done correct. because it only gave me to choose one option: 'Enable website hosting' or 'Redirect all requests to another host name' (so I chose 'Redirect all requests to another host name'). Are you 100% sure about this? @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @ElectricWizard my mistake, I said "enable static website hosting" but I should have said "**under** the static website hosting section" you want to select the "Redirect all requests to another hostname." So, it sounds like you got that part right.

Comment: @ElectricWizard I suspect your DNS changes have not had enough time and you are still trying to hit the old server.  If you want to mention your domain name in comments, I can check it out to confirm, and then you can remove that comment.  Or email it [to me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot?tab=profile).

Comment: Hi Michael - sqlbot, Can you please review this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/735481/sender-address-rejected-domain-not-found-after-route-53-amazon-aws-changes and tell me if the problem might be related to the changes made?